# Looping through a nested NSMutableDictionary and filtering some items

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, nested-loops, nsmutabledictionary

I have been stuck here for a while trying many things without any success.
So i have a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
{"Div 3 Mellersta G\u00f6taland, herrar": {
    "0": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Hestrafors IF", "tempTime": "12:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Gunnilse IS", "time": "90'", "events": []}, 
    "1": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Lerums IS", "tempTime": "13:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Skara FC", "time": "44'", "events": []}, 
    "2": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Vara SK ", "tempTime": "14:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "IFK Falk\u00f6ping FF", "time": "14:00", "events": []}, 
    "3": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Holmalunds IF Alings\u00e5s", "tempTime": "15:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Lunden \u00d6ver\u00e5s BK", "time": "15:00", "events": []}, 
    "4": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IFK Tidaholm", "tempTime": "16:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "S\u00e4vedalens IF", "time": "16:00", "events": []}}, 
"Div 4 A Herrar": {
    "0": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "SKIF Semberija", "tempTime": "17:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Floda BoIF", "time": "17:00", "events": []}, 
    "1": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Partille IF FK", "tempTime": "18:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Kode IF", "time": "18:00", "events": []}, 
    "2": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IK Kongah\u00e4lla", "tempTime": "19:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Romelanda UF", "time": "19:00", "events": []}}}
```

What i need to do is to iterate through all the items here to access the key/value pair **time** and if the time value has a value from 0 - 90 i want to save it.

What is important here is that the structure is not changed. By that i mean lets say for example we made an iteration over all the items and checked the time value, then the NEW dictionary would look like:

```
{"Div 3 Mellersta G\u00f6taland, herrar": {
    "0": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Hestrafors IF", "tempTime": "12:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Gunnilse IS", "time": "90'", "events": []}, 
    "1": {"awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Lerums IS", "tempTime": "13:00", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Skara FC", "time": "44'", "events": []}, 
}}
```

all the other items are filtered away since the first two items in **Div 3 Mellersta** was the only ones with the time value of 0 - 90.

Note it should be written in Objective-C

Thank you all!

Comment: You could use a `NSPredicate`.

Comment: At this point i would really love some code examples if you could provide it. But in the meantime i will look into it if nobody will know the solution to this. Thank you @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[rootDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key1, NSDictionary *dict1, BOOL *stop) {
    [dict1 enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key2, NSDictionary *dict2, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *time = dict2[@"time"];
        if([time integerValue] >= 0 && [time integerValue] <= 90 && ![time containsString:@":"]) {
            if(!newDict[key1]) {
                newDict[key1] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            }
            newDict[key1][key2] = dict2;
        }
    }];
}];
```

Comment: I dont know how to say this. But i love u. Thank you